# How do I get my django code to redirect users accordingly

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, django-views, response.redirect

I'm want my code to redirect students and teachers to two different pages when the login button is clicked but i kept getting this error:
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'is_teacher'

Here is my login view code:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if request.user.is_teacher:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('/myapp/home')
                else:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/myapp/application')
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password")
    return render(request, 'login.html',context={'form':AuthenticationForm()})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `user.is_teacher`, since that is the user you are authenticating. `request.user` is at that moment the `AnonymousUser`:

```
if user is not None:
    if user.is_teacher:  # 🖘 not request.user.is_teacher
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/myapp/home')
```

You can also simplify your view to:

```
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                if user.is_teacher:
                    return redirect('/myapp/home')
                else:
                    return redirect('/myapp/application')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password')
            form = AuthenticationForm()
```

Normally a [**`redirect(…)`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) also takes the *name* of the view, not a path or URL.

Comment: i changed to user.is_teacher but it keeps redirecting me to application

Comment: @MuhammadMangaBappah: are you sure `is_teacher` is set to `True` for that user?

Comment: thank you very much sir, it worked. turns out that i did not set is_teacher to True.